# SQL Join Tables Apply Value Only Once To Each Set

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to join two tables together. However, the table being joined must only apply its value once to a set a rows with the same value. This is what I mean...

**TABLE JOIN I WANT IS BELOW**

```
** LOGGED HOURS **   ** SICK HOURS **        ** RESULT TABLE **
+--------+-------+  +--------+-------+  +--------+-------+-------+
|Name    | Hours |  |Name    | Hours |  |Name    |Hours  |Sick   |
+--------+-------+  +--------+-------+  +--------+-------+-------+
|David   |47     |  |David   |9      |  |David   |47     |9      |
+--------+-------+  +--------+-------+  +--------+-------+-------+
|David   |9      |                      |David   |9      |0      |
+--------+-------+                      +--------+-------+-------+
```

**NORMAL LEFT TABLE JOIN RESULT:**

```
** LOGGED HOURS **   ** SICK HOURS **        ** RESULT TABLE **
+--------+-------+  +--------+-------+  +--------+-------+-------+
|Name    | Hours |  |Name    | Hours |  |Name    |Hours  |Sick   |
+--------+-------+  +--------+-------+  +--------+-------+-------+
|David   |47     |  |David   |9      |  |David   |47     |9      |
+--------+-------+  +--------+-------+  +--------+-------+-------+
|David   |9      |                      |David   |9      |9      |
+--------+-------+                      +--------+-------+-------+
```

Notice, 9 is applied to EACH row in a normal left table join. I want 9 to be applied ONLY ONCE to the set of rows whose name is DAVID.

Feel free to as any questions, thanks.

EDIT: If you're going to down-vote my question, please provide the courtesy of explaining why and how I can improve my question in the future. Thank you.

Comment: What is a "Name Category Value"? Is that a field that you aren't showing here that exists on both tables? Can you update your schema in the above examples to reflect that field.

Comment: I don't think you understand the concept of a JOIN. Please update your question to better explain your desired result. Maybe some context would help?

Comment: Name category value: basically all rows which share the same value in some column. E.g. select all rows whose name is David. that set of rows.

Comment: I understand what a join does. What i'm asking for is something that gives me the result I would like above.

Comment: But both of your tables have a "David" How does the database (or us humans) know which record in your desired result set should get the `9` from the `Sick table`? What is the logic that your record with `47` should get the `9`, but not the record with `9` from the `logged hours` table?

Comment: @StephenLasky given the table structure in the question, that will be impossible using any form of join.

Comment: Any arbitrary record may get the value. As long as only one record and not all records who share the same name.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: @ChrisPickford I've simplified the above table design for better understanding, the real tables have over 50 columns.

Comment: @ChrisPickford I'm not necessarily asking for a table join, just any piece of code which will combine the above tables while only applying the SICKHOURS number 9 only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you just want a single record for each "Name" to get your sick hours and the selection can be arbitrary, you can use a Window Function:

```
SELECT
    LoggedHours.Name,
    LoggedHours.Hours,
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LoggedHours.Name ORDER BY 1) = 1 THEN SickHours.Hours ELSE NULL END AS SickHoursLogged
FROM 
    LoggedHours LEFT OUTER JOIN SickHours on LoggedHours.Name = SickHours.Name
```

So... that Window/Analytics function says:

> Split the result set by Name (group of records with "David" for
>   example) and order them by whatever. Then give that group of records
>   row numbers starting at 1. If this particular record is row 1, then it
>   gets the sick hours from the `SickHours` table. Otherwise it gets
>   Null.

If... you wanted it to not be arbitrary, but instead wanted the record with the largest logged hours for each person to get the sick hours, you could change that ROW_NUMBER() function to:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LoggedHours.Name ORDER BY LoggedHours.Hours DESC) = 1
```

Comment: Would this not cause some SickHoursLogged to get a NULL value?

Comment: This would definitely cause some SickHoursLogged to get a NULL value. If you want a 0 instead, then change that NULL to a 0.